# How to ref a TextInput from one screen in another screen in Kivy/Python?

Tags: python, kivy, nameerror

I'm trying to make an app that can calculate the volume of a cone(so far). 
I have a screen named ConeVolumeScreen that has two TextInput widgets.

```
<ConeVolumeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: ...
        padding: ...
        spacing: ...
        Label:
            text: 'Radius:'
        TextInput:
            id: cone_vol_radius
            multiline: False
            input_type: 'number'
        Label:
            text: 'Height:'
        TextInput:
            id: cone_vol_height
            multiline: False
            input_type: 'number'
        Button:
            text: 'Solve'
            on_release: app.root.changeScreen('solve cone volume')
```

A person is supposed to enter the radius and height of the cone into these two widgets. Then the person can click on a button to go to the next screen named SolveConeVolumeScreen. In this screen there is a Label that should print the volume of the cone that the person specified.

```
<SolveConeVolumeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: ...
        padding: ...
        spacing: ...
        Label:
            text: app.getConeVolume(cone_vol_radius, cone_vol_height)
```

getConeVolume() is a method over here

```
class CalculatorRoot(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CalculatorRoot, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen_list = []

    def changeScreen(self, next_screen):
        if self.ids.calc_screen_manager.current not in self.screen_list:
            self.screen_list.append(self.ids.calc_screen_manager.current)

        if next_screen == 'volume':
            self.ids.calc_screen_manager.current = 'volume_screen'
        elif next_screen == 'area_screen':
            self.ids.calc_screen_manager.current = 'area_screen'
        elif next_screen == 'surface area':
            self.ids.calc_screen_manager.current = 'surfarea_screen'
        elif next_screen == 'cone volume':
            self.ids.calc_screen_manager.current = 'coneVolume_screen'
        elif next_screen == 'solve cone volume':
            self.ids.calc_screen_manager.current = 'solveConeVolume_screen'
        elif next_screen == 'rectangular based pyramid volume':
            self.ids.calc_screen_manager.current = 'rectPyramidVolume_screen'

    def onBackButton(self):
        if self.screen_list:
            self.ids.calc_screen_manager.current = self.screen_list.pop()
            return True
        return False



class CalculatorApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CalculatorApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.onBackButton)

    def onBackButton(self, window, key, *args):
        if key == 27:
            return self.root.onBackButton()

    def build(self):
        return CalculatorRoot()

    def getConeVolume(self, r, h):
        first_step = 'π * ' + str(r) + '^2 * ' + str(h) + ' / 3\n'
        rr = round(r * r, 2)
        second_step = 'π * ' + str(rr) + ' * ' + str(h) + ' / 3\n'
        rh = round(rr * h, 2)
        third_step = 'π * ' + str(rh) + ' / 3\n'
        pirh = round(pi * rh, 2)
        fourth_step = str(pirh) + ' / 3\n'
        result = round(pi * rh, 2)
        final_step = 'The answer is ' + str(result) + '.'
        thing = first_step + second_step + third_step + fourth_step + final_step
        return thing
```

But the error says that cone_vol_radius is not defined.

```
 ...
 128:        spacing: min(root.width, root.height) * .02
 129:        Label:
```

> > 130:            text: app.getConeVolume(cone_vol_radius, cone_vol_height) 
> >          131:
> >          132::
> >      ...
> >      BuilderException: Parser: File "/Users/fayzulloh/Desktop/Calculator App/calculator.kv", line 130:
> >      ...
> >          128:        spacing: min(root.width, root.height) * .02
> >          129:        Label:
> >      130:            text: app.getConeVolume(cone_vol_radius, cone_vol_height) 
> >          131:
> >          132::
> >      ...
> >      NameError: name 'cone_vol_radius' is not defined

please help. I would really appreciate any advice.

here is my screenmanager

```
<CalculatorRoot>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    ScreenManager:
        id: calc_screen_manager
        StartScreen:
            name: 'start_screen'
        VolumeScreen:
            id: volume_screen
            name: 'volume_screen'
        AreaScreen:
            id: area_screen
            name: 'area_screen'
        SurfaceAreaScreen:
            id: surfarea_screen
            name: 'surfarea_screen'
        ConeVolumeScreen:
            id: coneVolume_screen
            name: 'coneVolume_screen'
        SolveConeVolumeScreen:
            id: solveConeVolume_screen
            name: 'solveConeVolume_screen'
        RectPyramidVolumeScreen:
            id: rectPyramidVolume_screen
            name: 'rectPyramidVolume_screen'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Errors

There are a couple of errors in the application.

### NameError - Solution

Add `root.ids.ids.coneVolume_screen.ids.` to the arguments.

### AttributeError

After solving the NameError, an AttributeError will occurred. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'`. This is because inner ids are not available yet.

[Kivy Language » ids](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids)

> **Note** that the outermost widget applies the kv rules to all its inner widgets before any other rules are applied. ***This means if an
>   inner widget contains ids, these ids may not be available during the
>   inner widget’s `__init__` function.***

### AttributeError: ids - Solutions

1. Give an `id` to the Label e.g. `id: result`
2. Add an `on_pre_enter` event to invoke `getConeVolume()` method.
3. Replace TextInput object with TextInput's text i.e. replace `cone_vol_radius` and `cone_vol_height` with `cone_vol_radius.text` and `cone_vol_height.text` respectively.
4. Add `int()` function to convert TextInput's text/string to integer.

## Snippet

```
<SolveConeVolumeScreen>:
    on_pre_enter:
        root.ids.result.text = app.getConeVolume(int(app.root.ids.coneVolume_screen.ids.cone_vol_radius.text), int(app.root.ids.coneVolume_screen.ids.cone_vol_height.text))

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: result
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - ConeVolume Screen]
[image: Img02 - SolveConeVolume Screen]

Comment: CalculatorRoot is not a ScreenManager. But I do have a ScreenManager named calc_screen_manager in my CalculatorRoot. look at the new version of the question.

Comment: Oh man, it works. Thank you SO MUCH!!! I am super grateful. I can't put my gratefulness into words.