# Kivy - Get InputText From Other Screen

Tags: python, text, kivy

I am trying to type in text from one screen. Press a button and move to another screen and have that text be shown in a label. I've seen a few questions that are similar to mine, but have not been able to figure out how to use the posted solutions and have been stuck for hours ([Link One](https://programmer-rachel.medium.com/kivy-use-get-screen-to-access-objects-from-other-screens-8d4d6f288f3), [Link Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960386/kivy-use-text-from-textinput-of-one-screen-in-another-screen-in-py-file), [Link Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152053/how-to-ref-a-textinput-from-one-screen-in-another-screen-in-kivy-python)). I believe that I need to use the `__init__` method somewhere because this is an `instance`? I tried using the first link, but the label ends up blank (the code does run). Any Advice?

**main.py**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def get_unique_text(self):
        x = self.manager.get_screen("first")
        y = x.ids.unique.text
        return str(y)


class FirstWindow(Screen):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv_main = Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_main


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
#:include First.kv
#:include Second.kv

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Press"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "first"
```

**First.kv**

```
<FirstWindow@Screen>:
    name: "first"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Enter Unique Text for Saving"
            font_size: 20
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign: 'center'
        TextInput:
            id: unique
            hint_text: 'example: Stand25'
        Button:
            text: "Press"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"
```

**Second.kv**

```
<SecondWindow@Screen>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Unique Text"
            font_size: 20
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign: 'center'
        Label:
            text: root.get_unique_text()
            font_size: 16
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "first"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use the `on_enter()` method of a `Screen` in order to fetch the text. This also requires an `id` for the unique `Label`:

```
<SecondWindow@Screen>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Unique Text"
            font_size: 20
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign: 'center'
        Label:
            id: unique  # added id
            # text: root.get_unique_text()
            font_size: 16
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "first"
```

Just add an `on_enter()` method to the `SecondWindow` class:

```
class SecondWindow(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.unique.text = self.get_unique_text()

    def get_unique_text(self):
        x = self.manager.get_screen("first")
        y = x.ids.unique.text
        return str(y)
```

Comment: Thanks John! I will be incorporating this into my main project, so I will play with both to see what works. I did notice that the second method you posted, there was a slight delay for the text to display when pressing the button. Did you happen to notice that? It shouldn't be a problem, but why does that happen?

Comment: Yes, I did notice that. I think you can replace `on_enter()` with `on_pre_enter()` to eliminate that delay.

Comment: Yes that works. Appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

In your `Second.kv` you can reference the text of the `TextInput` in the `First.kv` by making a couple changes to the `kv` files. First, in the `main.kv`, add an `id` for the `FirstWindow` (and eliminate the `SecondWindow` for now):

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    FirstWindow:
        id: first  # added id
    # SecondWindow:  # this gets added later

<MainWindow>
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Press"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "first"
```

Then, in the `Second.kv`, set up the reference to the `text` of the `TextInput`:

```
<SecondWindow@Screen>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Unique Text"
            font_size: 20
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign: 'center'
        Label:
            text: app.root.ids.first.ids.unique.text  # reference to unique text
            font_size: 16
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "first"
```

Since the `kv` for `SecondWindow` uses `app.root`, it will cause an error if `SecondWindow` is instantiated before the root widget of the `App` is assigned. To avoid that, add the `SecondWindow` after a slight delay:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_second_screen)
        return kv_main

    def add_second_screen(self, dt):
        self.root.add_widget(SecondWindow())
```